# How can I delte widgets from screen? for loop and sqlite3

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, widget

How can I notify the user that the item was deleted when they press the "**Delete**" button in the function above? The data does get deleted, but the screen only updates once the user reopens the window. Ideally, I'd want all the three widgets: "**name_label; open_button; delete_button**" to disappear from the screen in the selected row and all the rows below to move up taking its place. Another idea I had is to config them with "**state=DISABLED**" or mark some way.

```
def delete(oid):
con = sqlite3.connect("recipe_book.db")
cur = con.cursor()
n = lookup_recipe(oid)[3]



name_label.config(state=DISABLED)
cur.execute("DELETE from recipes WHERE oid=" + str(n))

con.commit()
con.close()

def show():
    global oid
    global data
    global recipe_map
    global name_label

def on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1*int(event.delta/120), "units")

show_window = Toplevel(root)
show_window.grab_set()
container = Frame(show_window)
canvas = Canvas(container)

show_window.title("List of your recipes")
show_window.geometry("500x600+500+50")
show_window.resizable(0, 0)
show_window.iconbitmap("recipe.ico")
con = sqlite3.connect("recipe_book.db")
cur = con.cursor()

canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)
scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

cur.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM recipes")
data = cur.fetchall()

recipe_map = {object_id: (name, ingredients, cooking_method,object_id)
              for name, ingredients, cooking_method, object_id in data}

for oid in recipe_map:
    title_label = Label(scrollable_frame, text="Saved Recipes:", font=("Helvetica",20))
    title_label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=(20, 30), columnspan=3,padx=150)
    name_label = Label(scrollable_frame, text=lookup_recipe(oid)[0],font=("Times New Roman",13),width=20,wraplength=250)
    name_label.grid(column=0, row=oid, pady=10,ipadx=1)
    open_button = Button(scrollable_frame, text="Open", command=lambda i=oid: showit(i),width=5)
    open_button.grid(column=1,row=oid,padx=(70, 0))
    delete_button = Button(scrollable_frame, text="Delete", command=lambda i=oid: delete(i),width=5)
    delete_button.grid(column=2,row=oid, padx=(0, 70))

container.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nse",ipadx=120,ipady=165)
canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nse", ipadx=90,ipady=165)
if len(data) > 11:
    scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nse", ipadx=60,ipady=165)

con.commit()
con.close()

def lookup_recipe(object_id):
    return (recipe_map[object_id])
```

Comment: ok come back when you have tried your ideas and haven't succeeded, also please provide a [mre] and fix your indentations

Comment: What about grid_forget?

Comment: You need another `dict` to store the widgets created for each record using `oid` as the key.  Then extract the widgets from this `dict` inside `delete()` and call `destroy()` on those widgets extracted.

Comment: @acw1668 I added `widget_map = {oid: (name_label, open_button, delete_button)}` into `for oid in recipe_map:`. `open_button` and `delete_button` are considered undefined outside of the loop. When I try to extract the widgets inside `delete()`, it only acknowledges the last added row.

Comment: Since you put `widget_map = {oid: (...)}` inside the for loop, `widget_map` will contain only the last item.  You need to initialize `widget_map` before for loop and add `widget_map[oid] = (...)` inside the for loop.